# SQL query to select from two tables with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables Notification and Acknowledgment. Acknowledgment has a field which holds the primary key of Notification table. Basically a Notification will have many Acknowledgments.

```
Tables: Notification        Acknowledgment

fields: id, notifier        id, parent_id, status
```

Now I have to choose rows from Notification such that:

1. there is no Acknowledgment WHERE Acknowledment.parent_id = Notification.id (basically no Acknowledgment for that particular Notification)
   //or
2. if there is an Acknowledgment for Notification, then select Notification if any of the Acknowledgments with parent_id = Notification.id has a Acknowledgment.status = someValue

A pseudo SQL code:

```
   "SELECT * FROM Notification (WHERE id is not present in Acknowledgment.parent_id) OR
   (WHERE id is present in Acknowledgment.parent_id AND Acknowledgment.status=@someValue"
```

I can break it into simpler queries and achieve this, but I would love to know one single query to get this done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT    * 
    FROM    Notification n
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Acknowledgment a ON a.parent_id = n.id
  WHERE     (a.parent_id IS NULL OR a.status = @somevalue)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `LEFT OUTER JOINS`, you can use [the `EXISTS` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

For your example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Notification n
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM Acknowledgement
   WHERE parent_id = n.id
) OR EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM Acknowledgement
   WHERE parent_id = n.id AND status = @someValue
)
```

`JOIN`s tend to be better optimized in SQL (particularly where, as in my example, you are using more than one on the same table), I just mention this alternative as it is a more direct translation of your pseudo-query.

Comment: Thanks.. this is different and simpler but more verbose. Thanks for letting me know these kinda key words. Its easier to remember

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.* FROM Notification n
LEFT OUTER JOIN Acknowledgment a ON a.parent_id=n.id
WHERE a.status IS NULL OR a.status=@someValue
```

Comment: @Akhil 's answer has a.id IS NULL instead of a.status in your code. Is it ok to go for either since there wont be such a row anyway?

Comment: @Akhil, why did you update, when it makes absolutely no difference in result? :)

Comment: Infact, you cannot assume a.status IS NULL works unless status is a NON NULLABLE column. If it is nullable, there may be an Acknowledgement with a Parent_id but no status. In which case your logic may not work!

Comment: @Akhil spot on! though in my case status wont be null. Anyway im going to mark yours answer for being few seconds faster..

Comment: Thank You! Good that status is not Null. Ideally it could be a Non-Nullable Foreign Key to a Status table.

Comment: @Akhil @nawful It does not matter that the column is non-nullable: if the outer-joined row is missing, the column in the result would contain `null`.

Comment: @nawfal Don't worry about it, everyone knows that questions like that are "speed typing contests" :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, what you said is right,except your join condition is on parent_id. If at all there is an acknowledgement having a valid parent_id but a NULL status (assuming status is null), would your query return that? if it returns its not something query is expecting :)

Comment: @Akhil You are correct: if the status happens to be nullable, you might get "false positives".

Comment: @nawfal Since your status is non-nullable anyway, everyone's right :)